# rename files in folder containg special characters linux

Tags: linux, rename

I have a lot of files containing percent signs other special characters

I ran this command in the current directory but its not working...

rename 's/%//g' *

on Linux centos

Comment: It seems to work for me for files containing %, $, ^, etc.  Your command simply removes the first % character from the file name.  **Please explain what you desire and expect to happen, and what is actually happening.**

Comment: %  can be anywhere in the file name..

Comment: I guess the proble mis I need Perl rename.. thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You expect perl's rename

Remove `-n` switch when the output looks good.

[image: warning] **There are other tools with the same name which may or may not be able to do this, so be careful.**

If you run the following command (`GNU`)

```
$ file "$(readlink -f "$(type -p rename)")"
```

and you have a result that contains `Perl script, ASCII text executable` and not containing `ELF`, then this seems to be the right tool =)

If not, to make it the default (usually already the case) on `Debian` and derivative like `Ubuntu` :

```
$ sudo update-alternatives --set rename /path/to/rename
```

Replace `/path/to/rename` to the path of your `perl rename` executable.

---

If you don't have this command, search your package manager to install it or [do it manually](https://metacpan.org/module/RMBARKER/File-Rename-0.20/rename.PL) (no deps...)

---

<sub><sup>This tool was originally written by Larry Wall, the Perl's dad.</sup></sub>

Comment: thanks I did and it said 
/usr/bin/rename: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.18, stripped

Comment: try this : `yum install  Perl-rename`

Comment: No package Perl-rename available.

Comment: I guess the proble mis I need Perl rename.. thank you  I will lask my host to try to allow to get perl rename install yum